# Python Case proofing comparison of 2 string lists and returning specific version of string

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists containing headers for a what will become spreadsheet headers, I need to remove headers which the user has marked to ignore. This functions fine but I would like make the header removal case insensitive. Currently I can only get case sensitive solutions to work using set.intersection but cant find a way to get the outcome needed.
Example of desired outcome below:

```
user_removal_list = [headerone , headerTwo, HeaderThree]
l2 = [HeaderOne,HeaderTwo,HeaderThree,HeaderFour,etc.....]
#Some handling to result in:
list_of_matching_strings = [HeaderOne,HeaderTwo,HeaderThree]
```

As said above I have no problem getting the case sensitive comparison but because I need the final list to have the camel case style, need some direction

The example above is just an demo of the outcome the names in the list could be anything as they come from the columns returned from DB procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem. Initially I was thinking there would be some sort of function that could do it in a cleaner way but this is what works currently:

```
for string in user_removal_list:
  for header in l2:
    if string.lower().strip() == header.lower():
      matching_strings.append(header)
```

I have added the strip to remove whitespace as the user removal list originates from a config file and without it the value was not getting picked up

Answer (score 0):

**List comprehension:**

```
camel_user_removal_list = [user_removal_list[0][0:6].capitalize() + user_removal_list[0][6:].capitalize() for string in user_removal_list]
```

or **For loop:**

```
i = 0
camel_user_removal_list = []
for string in user_removal_list:
    camel_header = user_removal_list[i][0:6].capitalize() + user_removal_list[i][6:].capitalize()
    camel_user_removal_list.append(camel_header)
    i += 1
```

**Output:**

```
['HeaderOne', 'HeaderTwo', 'HeaderThree']
```

Comment: This is just making the user removal list camel case correct? The problem with this is the headers from the user_removal_list aren't going to be headerOne etc they are going to be actual fields from tables in a database as this is part of a bigger program

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. My solution works only in this specific case (f. ex. only where the word "header" has six letters).

Comment: Yeah that's on me should have been more clear. But I like what you did